# Flutter image picker not providing the image path

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get a image using camera in flutter using image picker but i am getting an error

```
          lib/Screen/AllDocuments.dart:15:3: Error: 'File' isn't a type.
          File _image;
```

I have also tried to cast but still it is not working

```
       File _image;
   final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

setState(() {
    _image = File(pickedFile);
  });
}
```

How to fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `.path` method on the `pickedFile`.
See this documentation here => [Image Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

Use this :

```
 File _image;
   final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

setState(() {
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
  });
}
```